# Access denied to S3 bucket from Athena although permissions = allow all

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I followed the tutorial http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html. I set up a IAM user (with strange permissions) and a S3-bucket and could query sample Athena tables and the outputs were written to my S3-bucket. 
Now I have credentials from a client to access his Athena table. This doesn't work and I get following error:

> Access denied when writing output to url:
>   s3://my-test-bucket/b36-f3c0-482-a225-34d63d355.txt . Please ensure
>   you are allowed to access the S3 bucket. If you are encrypting query
>   results with KMS key, please ensure you are allowed to access your KMS
>   key

My S3-bucket is as public as it gets.
Permissions for "Any authenticated AWS user" : Read, Write.
Permissions for "everyone" : Read, Write.
Permissions for "Log delivery" : Read, Write.
"Permission Access" for everything: Read, Write

Bucket Policy allows everyone to do everything.

```json
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
     {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": "*",
         "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket"
     },
     {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": "*",
         "Action": [
             "s3:PutObject",
             "s3:GetObject",
             "s3:DeleteObject"
         ],
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/*"
     },
     {
         "Sid": "AddPerm",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": "*",
         "Action": [
             "s3:GetObject",
             "s3:PutObject"
         ],
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/*"
     }
 ] }
```

CORS configuration:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <CORSConfiguration
 xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"> <CORSRule>
     <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
     <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
     <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
     <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
     <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader> </CORSRule> </CORSConfiguration>
```

Still, I get the error:  Access denied when writing output to url...

Edit: From time to time I get an other error instead: "Unable to verify/create output bucket my-test-bucket". Not sure why I get different errors.

What can I do?

Comment: I had the same issue :( Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Had an almost similar issue with a particular file on s3. I could not read the file. Solved the issue by changing the access permissions of the file using the mv command and the `--acl` argument. Trying to access a file called `data.jsonlines` gave the `ACCESS DENIED` error. Solved it by running the following commands:

NOTE: You will need to have the [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html) installed: `$ pip install --upgrade --user awscli`

```
aws s3 cp s3://<s3 bucket name>/path/to/file/data.jsonlines  s3://cfa-opengazettes-ke/gazettes/data_copy.jsonlines 

aws s3 mv --acl public-read s3://<s3 bucket name>/path/to/file/data_copy.jsonlines s3://cfa-opengazettes-ke/gazettes/data.jsonlines
```

Or you can **combine** them by running:

```
aws s3 cp s3://<s3 bucket name>/path/to/file/data_out.jsonlines  s3://cfa-opengazettes-ke/gazettes/data_out2.jsonlines && aws s3 mv --acl public-read s3://cfa-opengazettes-ke/gazettes/data_out2.jsonlines s3://<s3 bucket name>/path/to/file/data_out.jsonlines
```

These commands carry out the steps below:

- copy: `s3://<s3 bucket name>/path/to/file/data.jsonlines` to
  `s3://c<s3 bucket name>/path/to/file/data_copy.jsonlines`
- move: `s3://<s3 bucket name>/path/to/file/data_copy.jsonlines` to
  `s3://cfa-opengazettes-ke/path/to/file/data.jsonlines`

Basically, it creates a copy of the file and then deletes it during the move while changing the permissions of the file.

Note the `--acl` option and the argument `public-read`. Maybe one of the below permissions could work for you. You can replace `public-read` with another permission. From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html#options):

> --acl (string) Sets the ACL for the object when the command is performed. If you use this parameter you must have the
>   "s3:PutObjectAcl" permission included in the list of actions for your
>   IAM policy. Only accepts values of **private**, **public-read**,
>   **public-read-write**, **authenticated-read**, **aws-exec-read**,
>   **bucket-owner-read**, **bucket-owner-full-control** and **log-delivery-write**.

Some more useful information at this [AWS page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html)